Characterization of duals of Sobolev space.
Proposition 8.14. in Brezis states that:$(W_0^{1,p} (Ω))^*=W^{-1,p^*} (Ω)$ and  we have the representation:
$∀ F∈(W_0^{1,p} (Ω))^* ∃ f_0...f_n ∈L^{p^*} (Ω)$   such that $∀ u∈W_0^{1,p}(Ω)$
$F(u)=∫_Ω uf_0dx+∑_{i=1}^N∫_Ωf_i  ∂_i udx$
Where:
$∂_i$ is  the distribution of derivative with respect to the $i$ variable.
and remark 21 states that this representation is a valid for $F∈(W^{1,p} (Ω))^*$  as well.
my question is regarding remark 20 on the same page. It states that F can be identified with the distribution $f_0-∑_{i=1}^n∂_i f_i$  without adding any clarification. So I was curious if this distribution  representation can be useful.  The idea is this:
the distribution $f_0-∑_{i=1}^n∂_i f_i$  can't act on $W_0^{1,p} (Ω)$  functions,  but it can act and test functions so  take a sequence of test functions $ϕ_n$ converging to $u$ in $W_0^{1,p} (Ω)$.  We have that:
$F(u)=lim_{n→∞}⁡ ∫_Ω ϕ_n f_0dx+∑_{i=1}^N∫_Ω f_i ∂_i ϕ_n dx.$  This is because F it's a continuous linear functional and $ϕ_n→u$ in $W_0^{1,p} (Ω)$.  Now we'll using this fact and  considering $⟨*,*⟩$ the dual bracket in $D^* (Ω)×D(Ω)$ we can do the following:
$F(u)=lim_{n→∞}⁡ ∫_Ω ϕ_n f_0dx+∑_{i=1}^N∫_Ω f_i ∂_i ϕ_n dx=lim_{n→∞}⟨f_0,ϕ_n⟩+∑_{i=1}^N⟨f_i,∂_i ϕ_n⟩=lim_{n→∞}⟨f_0-∑_{i=1}^n∂_i f_i,ϕ_n⟩$
I am particularly interested in the last line, which gives a connection between F and its distribution representative. Please tell me if the above calculation are correct
